# What is the role of npartitions in a Dask dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I see the paramter `npartitions` in many functions, but I don't understand what it is good for / used for.

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv

> head(...)
>
> Elements are only taken from the first npartitions, with a default of 1. If there are fewer than n rows in the first npartitions a warning will be raised and any found rows returned. Pass -1 to use all partitions.
>
> repartition(...)
>
> Number of partitions of output, must be less than npartitions of input. Only used if divisions isn’t specified.

Is the number of partitions probably 5 in this case:

(Image source: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-overview.html )

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `npartitions` property is the number of Pandas dataframes that compose a single Dask dataframe.  This affects performance in two main ways.

1. If you don't have enough partitions then you may not be able to use all of your cores effectively.  For example if your dask.dataframe has only one partition then only one core can operate at a time.
2. If you have too many partitions then the scheduler may incur a lot of overhead deciding where to compute each task.

Generally you want a few times more partitions than you have cores.  Every task takes up a few hundred microseconds in the scheduler.

You can determine the number of partitions either at data ingestion time using the parameters like `blocksize=` in `read_csv(...)` or afterwards by using the `.repartition(...)` method.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to check what is the optimal number for my case.
I work on laptops with 8 cores.
I have 100Gb csv files  with 250M rows and 25 columns.
I run  the function "describe" on 1,5,30,100  partitions

```
df = df.repartition(npartitions=1)
a1=df['age'].describe().compute()
df = df.repartition(npartitions=5)
a2=df['age'].describe().compute()
df = df.repartition(npartitions=30)
a3=df['age'].describe().compute()
df = df.repartition(npartitions=100)
a4=df['age'].describe().compute()
```

about speed :

5,30 >  around 3 minutes

1, 100 >  around 9 minutes

but ...I found that "order" functions like median or percentile give wrong number when I used more than one  partition .

1 partition give right number (I checked it with  small data using pandas and dask)

Comment: According to your snippet, I think you meant 100 partitions, not 1000.

Comment: thank's .  i changed to 100 :)