# Dask: Memory efficient way aggregating different slices of dataframe and merging together

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-computing, dask, dask-distributed

I have a Dask dataframe (`df`) of order histories for customers that I read in from a csv file.

Except:

```
| customer_id | order_date | order_number |   sales  |
|-------------|------------|--------------|----------|
|  109230900  |  20190104  |   order101   |  210.50  |
```

I first get total sum of sales per customer. Next I want to get aggregates of sales for different date intervals: sales within  the last 7 days, last 14 days, and last 30 days. Today's date is `20190104` (YYYYMMDD).

Here's the result I want:

```
| customer_id | total_sales | sales_for_past_7_days |   sales_for_past_14_days |   sales_for_past_30_days |
|-------------|-------------|-----------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|  109230900  |   5105.10   |         210.50        |           320.00         |           1045.05        |
```

My attempt:

```
import datetime as dt
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()

df = dd.read_csv('order_history.csv', blocksize = 10e6)

total_sales = df.groupby('customer_id').agg({'sales':'sum'}, split_out=100).rename(columns={'sales':'total_sales'})`

total_sales = client.persist(total_sales)

end_date = dt.datetime.strptime('20190104','%Y%m%d') 

for interval in [7,14,30]:
    start_date = int(end_date - dt.timedelta(days=interval )).strftime('%Y%m%d'))
    newcol = 'sales_for_past_{}_days'.format(interval)

    tempdf = df[df.order_date > start_date].groupby('CUSTOMER_ID')

    tempagg = tempdf.agg({'sales':'sum'}, split_out=100).rename(columns={'sales':newcol})

    total_sales = dd.merge(total_sales, tempagg, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)

total_sales = client.persist(total_sales)

print(total_sales.head())
```

Is there a smarter way of doing this? When running above code, I get numerous warning messages about memory issues and there being too many tasks. There seem to be about 2 million tasks, btw.

All of this running as single-machine cluster on a Linux box with 16GB of RAM and 16 cores. The code is run as a Python script and not in Jupyter Notebook.

```
python==3.7.0
dask==1.0.0
distributed=1.25.1
tornado==5.1
```

Comment: Could I ask you what's the meaning of `split_out` in aggregate?

Comment: I use `split_out` to ensure I have partitions in dataframe after the groupby because a groupby returns a single partition by default. In my case, where I'm grouping by customer_id, I will have A LOT of groups and I thought having a single partition might make things slower. Here's where I got the idea: https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/02-groupby.html.

Although, I'm starting to think 100 partitions may be too much. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645477/what-is-the-role-of-npartitions-in-a-dask-dataframe

Comment: I was wondering what would be a pandas' solution to this problem but I wasn't able to find a nice answer.